# How to start Gameroom login integratoin for Unity games?

Tags: facebook, facebook-gameroom

["Gameroom(windows)"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Zn0x.png)

I'm trying to integrate our game with Facebook Gameroom. The first step is Login integration.
Seems, the official SDK does not support "Gameroom(windows)" Login.

Where can I find the unity SDK that supported "Gameroom(windows)" Login?

Has anyone integrated with Gameroom before?
Thanks.

Comment: I have the same question,waitting for answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question up until yesterday. I would direct you to this link: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/gameroom
You want to use at least Unity 5.6.2 and use the Facebook Gameroom (Windows Native) build included in Unity. Use the 7.10 SDK (choose it from the dropdown it'll say 'Facebook SDK 7.10.1') on the Build Settings screen.
The link that I gave is needed as once you have the build set up there's a lot of things that you need to do to make it work, and the link will help you through that. (On the page in the documentation, there's a link that will take you to the build and testing page - it's the second set of instructions).
I'm currently in the process of porting over a Mobile game to FB Gameroom, so I am going through it myself. Oh! and you'll want to have the 7.10.0 Facebook SDK (available from Facebook) as a .unitypackage file.
The reason for the unity package version is that you will seriously want the examples directory and scripts so that you can implement facebook's api. Do NOT install the entire package as that will blow everything up, just need the scripts and the scenes.
That should get you started. Also, a tech-tip... if you are using UNITY IAP, it will log into facebook on its own (to set up the codeless IAP stuff). I found that out AFTER I modified the examples to handle the login and initialization of the Facebook API.

Good Luck!!!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Michieal. I will try it out.

Comment: Good luck. for me its been slamming my head into a brick wall, and expecting the wall to move. :P

Comment: Hi Michieal, Seems I might need further helps. The link you sent does not include anything about Facebook login. The unity plug-in only support mobile and WebGL login, I can not find the support for "Gameroom(Windows)" Login.  Have you found any way to achieve the "Gameroom(Windows)" login?

Comment: Updates:  Login and payment integration finished. We can run the game without any problem in Unity Editor. But the keyboard is not responding when we run it inside Gameroom frame, only the mouse works fine.

Please help.

We've nearly finished the integration with Gameroom including Login and Payment. This is the last barrier we have now before we can release the game.

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I believe that FB.Login() and FB.IsLoggedIn will log you in and allow you to check to see if the user is logged in (respectively).
As far as capturing the keyboard input... I would say to switch the game to fullscreen mode, and try it there. Otherwise, I would offer the player the option of using a gamepad (if the keypresses are for movement) or make buttons in the UI for keypresses. Like, instead of using Ctrl-S for saving progress, put in a save progress button in the UI. Though, the Input.GetButton("Fire") etc., does work in place of Input.GetKey().